# Program an Arduino Uno with an Atmel ICE

Tags: atmel-studio

When I connected my atmel ice to my arduino uno everything went okay.
Then I tried debugWIRE and since then I can't connect to my ATMEGA328p.
I get the error 
`Failed to enter programming mode. ispEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)`
I think one of the fuse bits is wrong but can't connect to the ATMEGA328p to change them. Does anyone have a idea what to do?

Comment: *I can't connect to my ATMEGA328p* - connect using what? If you try to connect it using the "regular" USB, then it won't work until you flash the bootloader using ICE. You have probably overwritten it.

Comment: Have you looked up the problem with Atmel? It's like I always tell people on here... You're not discovering new problems when you encounter a problem. The chances of an error happening to you and someone else having the same problem is extremely high... But this looks like a physical connection problem (i.e. a lose wire, bad connection between components, clock frequencies etc).

Comment: @EugeneSh. The poster is asking how to program the Arduino with the Atmel Ice programmer after debugging with debugWIRE. No bootloader required.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ardunino is stuck in debugWIRE (The debug wire fuse is set). Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJKoc_TI2sw) on how to get it back to programming mode.

In the tutorial I am using the AVR Dragon with AS6, but the process is the same with Atmel ICE and AS7.

You have to be in Debug Mode to disable debugWIRE. While in debug, Click Debug>Disable Debug Wire and Close.